# Why does `{foo: 1}` evaluate to `1` in the console, and `{foo: 1, bar: 2}` results in an error?

Tags: javascript

I knew that `{}` is either an object or a block of code, but today my co-worker asked me why `{foo: 1}` works when entered into the console, but `{foo: 1, bar: 2}` generates an error.

Why does `foo: 1` evaluate in the console to `1`?

Comment: Depending on the context, `{}` most certainly can be an (empty) object (literal). How are you printing?

Comment: "print" == execute in the console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By itself, `{a: 1}` is a block statement, where `a` is a label.

Of course, in a context where an expression is expected, it is an object literal:

```
var o = { a: 1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on context:

```
function test() {
   var foo = {a:1}; // this is an object
   { alert('Hi mom!'); } // this is a block of code
   { a: 1 }; // also just a block of code, but `a:` is a label
}
```

If the `{}` block is used in an (in)equality test (`==`, `===`, `!=`, etc...) or an assignment (`=`), then it's an object. All other contexts would be "just a block of code".

Comment: Actually, it would be an object wherever an expression is expected, which is true in situations other than tests and assignments. To take just one example, in `fun({a:1})`, when used as a function parameter, it's parsed as an object literal.

Comment: technically, it's an assignment, because that value gets assigned to whatever variable is defined in the function's argument list.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sorry not to comment under your post due to lack of reputation.

can you elaborate more on "Why I can print foo: 1 in JavaScript"?

If I run this code

```
var t = {foo: 1};
```

It will become the property for object "t". The same behaviour will be implement if you use this code

```
var t = {foo: 1, bar: 2};
```

You can access it by "t.foo" and "t.bar" and it will return the value either "1" or "2".

You can read the explanation of "object" here [JavaScript Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)